# Python: get indices of elements that are in a streak of at least 3?

Tags: python, python-itertools

(this isn't homework, I'm teaching myself)

I have a dictionary (actually a `Counter`) with some counting numbers (call this `n`) and how many times that number occured (call this `c`). i.e.

```
my_dict = { n0: c0, n1: c1, ... , nx: cx }
```

I want to convert that to sublists of `c`'s if the `n`'s are sequential. i.e. if

```
my_dict = { 0: 1, 1: 1, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 1 }
```

I'd like

```
result = [ [ 1 , 1 ] , [ 1 , 2 , 1 ] ]
```

I could just use a for loop over the index, but that wouldn't be pythonic. However, at this point I'm using multiple `itertools` functions and still haven't gotten what I want.

Could I get a suggestion?

Comment: `for` loops *can* be pythonic...

Comment: the only way I was coming up with was very non-pythonic `for i in range...`

Comment: I just noticed: what's the significance of "streak of at least 3" in your title? Your actual question demonstrates grabbing all streak lengths (presuming that by "streak" you mean the indices are sequential).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `for` loop might be the simplest solution; iterating over the keys of the dictionary and whenever the key is not equal to the last key plus 1, starting a new list in the output, otherwise appending to the current list:

```
my_dict = { 0: 1, 1: 1, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 1 }

l = []
last = max(my_dict.keys())
for k, v in my_dict.items():
    if k != last + 1:
        l.append([v])
    else:
        l[-1].append(v)
    last = k
        
print(l)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 1], [1, 2, 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Functional programming can be horrific sometimes:

```
import functools

my_dict = { 0: 1, 1: 1, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 1 }
sorted_items = sorted(my_dict.items())

initial_data = [[sorted_items[0][1]]]
remaining_data = (
  {'value': value, 'should_merge': previous_key + 1 == key}
  for (previous_key, previous_value), (key, value)  in
  zip(sorted_items[1:], sorted_items[2:]) 
)

my_result = functools.reduce(
  lambda initial, data:
    initial[-1:] + [initial[-1] + [data['value']]] if data['should_merge'] else
    initial + [[data['value']]],
  remaining_data,
  initial_data
)
```